# From wstring to SQLCHAR

Tags: c++, wstring

what i need to do is to execute an SQL query:

```
wstring query = ( L "INSERT INTO database...........;
```

then i execute this:

```
CHECK( SQLExecDirectA( hStmt, query, SQL_NTS ), "execute query" );
```

but it doesn't compile, because the variable query must be an SQLCHAR otherwise function SQLExecDirectA wont work.

can anyone help please?

thanks!

Comment: Do you *have* to use wstring instead of string?

Comment: Besides the answer from David Feurle, you have to remember that `std::wstring` (or `std::string`) can not be converted directly to `wchar_t *` (or `char *`). You have to use e.g. `query.c_str()` to get a character pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you are trying to call is called SQLExecDirect. (Nearly) all the functions in the winapi exist in two version - a ascii version and a wide version. Depending on your project settings (Multibyte character set/Unicode) SQLExecDirect is a define to either SQLExecDirectA or SQLExecDirectW (with SQLExecDirectA beeing the ascci version and SQLExecDirectW beeing the wide version).

The SQLExecDirectA  means your are explicitely calling the ascii version with a wide string as parameter. Try calling SQLExecDirectW or SQLExecDirect if you want to use wide strings.